# Easy way to keep using current HEAD in Git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit

I have the following situation in Git: I did a lot of refactoring and detached the head because I went back and forth between versions a few times. Because of the detached head I am no longer able to commit to the origin/master remote branch.

[image: branches]

The HEAD is my version that I want to keep. What I tried is merging the origin/master remote branch into HEAD so I can commit that version back. During the merge I said I want to keep my own changes wherever there were conflicts.

The result was a mess with a lot of missing files. Luckily I made a file copy before the operation so I could go back to the situation that I just described.

Now I am stuck. I don't want to go through each and every change and decide what I want to keep (there are many). I only want to commit the lost HEAD back to origin/master, including the new directory structure. Any easy way to do that?

--

After I ran through the steps recommended by @Martin my status is now these (see comment as well):

[image: new status]

Comment: Solve the conflicts , and then merge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout master and merge your HEAD. I'm naming it good_stuff below to avoid ever having to know the sha-1...

(assuming everything is already committed on your current HEAD)

```
git checkout -b good_stuff HEAD
git checkout master
git merge good_stuff
```

solve conflicts

```
git commit
```

Comment: The first three commands completed fine and I have a merged version now, but the head is still detached. The branch I created during step 1 I called "refactored_version". When I try to commit I receive "Nothing to commit." I have posted a view of the current state as shown in Android Studio above.

Comment: @OliverHausler I suspect you forgot to checkout the new branch before merging.

Comment: It looks like you did not checkout master before merging. If you have a branch checked out and merge it you will still have it checked out after the merge, and the top of the branch will be your merge. You can fix the new situation by resetting --hard to your good commit, but make sure master is checked out when you do it

Answer (score 0):

when I am in a detached HEAD that I want to keep, I always first create a new branch on this point. Assuming you can use command line, this is the line:

```
git checkout -b branch_clean_version_of_stuff
```

now it will be easy to find back your work in the current condition. Also now you can merge back to origin master and push back to the origin.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this in the future, don't work on a detached HEAD, make a branch.  Branches in Git are practically free.

To deal with a detached HEAD that has work on it, make and check out a branch at the detached HEAD, `git checkout -b whatever`, and now treat it like a normal branch.  You can merge it into master as normal.

To solve your current problem where the merge is detached (I suspect you forgot to check out the new branch), note the commit ID of HEAD (or tag it), then...

- git checkout master
- git reset --hard

`git reset` will move branch labels to arbitrary commits.

Answer (score 0):

In the first picture, it is clear that HEAD is based on one commit back relative `master`. You had done a `git checkout HEAD^` on `master` to get into a detached state and then worked from there. Effectively, you're on a nameless branch. You can easily rebase this over top of `master`:

```
git rebase master
```

After the rebase, these changes will shoot from the tip of `master` rather than `master^`. In other words, the changes are now "fast-forward" relative to `master`.

At this point, you're still in a detached state. You can simply switch to `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

Git will warn you that you are leaving behind a detached state and give you the SHA.  Copy that SHA and do this:

```
# on master now
git rebase SHA   # fast-forward to SHA
```

Note: since we know that the update to move `master` to `SHA` is a fast-forward change, we could do it with `git reset --hard SHA` also.

If you do it this way with rebase, you avoid creating a messy, non-linear history characteristic of git merges.

Merges should only be done when you cannot rewrite history with rebasing (because the history has been published to other repositories). In this situation not only has the history not been published, but it doesn't even have a name!